# Order by working well in mysql but not in BIRT?

Tags: mysql, sql, birt

I have this query

```
select item.No_, item.Description,
group_concat(date_format(item_ledger_entry.Posting_Date,"%m/%d/%Y") separator '\n') AS Grouped_Date
from pbsdev3.item, pbsdev3.item_ledger_entry
where item.No_ = item_ledger_entry.Item_No_
group by No_
order by Posting_Date;
```

and the result in mysql db is this, which is correct

```
01/09/2009
01/09/2009
01/10/2009
```

but when I do it in my BIRT report designer, it is not in the same order anymore, here it is look like:

```
01/10/2009
01/09/2009
01/09/2009
```

I want it to be ordered descending. 
I tried `order by Posting_Date desc` or `asc` but result in birt is the same.

Why is this happening? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect?  You have not specified an ordering, so the ordering is arbitrary.  It might differ between two runs; it might differ across databases.

This is easy enough to fix:

```
select i.No_, i.Description,
       group_concat(date_format(ile.Posting_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') order by ile.Posting_date separator '\n' ) AS Grouped_Date
from pbsdev3.item i join
     pbsdev3.item_ledger_entry ile
     on i.No_ = ile.Item_No_
group by i.No_
order by ile.Posting_Date;
```

The `order by` specifies the ordering of the values.  This should return the same results on the two systems.